# get a part from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, url, pulse

i'm trying to get the pulse as an output for the given url using this code

```
from OTXv2 import OTXv2
from OTXv2 import IndicatorTypes
otx = OTXv2("my_key")
test=otx.get_indicator_details_full(IndicatorTypes.DOMAIN, "google.com")
```

and when i print test i become this output:

```
{'general': {'sections': ['general', 'geo', 'url_list', 'passive_dns', 'malware', 'whois', 'http_scans'], 'whois': 'http://whois.domaintools.com/google.com', 'alexa': 'http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/google.com', 'indicator': 'google.com', 'type': 'domain', 'type_title': 'Domain', 'validation': [{'source': 'ad_network', 'message': 'Whitelisted ad network domain www-google-analytics.l.google.com', 'name': 'Whitelisted ad network domain'}, {'source': 'akamai', 'message': 'Akamai rank: #3', 'name': 'Akamai Popular Domain'}, {'source': 'alexa', 'message': 'Alexa rank: #1', 'name': 'Listed on Alexa'}, {'source': 'false_positive', 'message': 'Known False Positive', 'name': 'Known False Positive'}, {'source': 'majestic', 'message': 'Whitelisted domain google.com', 'name': 'Whitelisted domain'}, {'source': 'whitelist', 'message': 'Whitelisted domain google.com', 'name': 'Whitelisted domain'}], 'base_indicator': {'id': 12915, 'indicator': 'google.com', 'type': 'domain', 'title': '', 'description': '', 'content': '', 'access_type': 'public', 'access_reason': ''}, 'pulse_info': {'count': 0, 'pulses': [], 'references': [], 'related': {'alienvault': {'adversary': [], 'malware_families': [], 'industries': []}, 'other': {'adversary': [], 'malware_families': [], 'industries': []}}}, 'false_positive':...
```

i want to get only the part `'count': 0` in `pulse_info`
i tried using test.values() but it's like i have many dictionaries together
any idea how can i solve that?
Thank you

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried. Do you know how to access values from a `dict`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(test["general"]["pulse_info"]["count"])
```